# Is it possible to have a J2ME app get an SMS and send it to a computer?

Tags: java-me, sms

That's basically my question, I have written the code for sending/receiving SMS but it's basically a "server/client" so I can't get the SMS that are sent directly to the phone number instead of through the j2me program. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to write an app that receives an incoming SMS, extracts the message and sends it to server through a HTTP call. You can then make that server send that SMS to another phone.

Comment: how? I have a server and a client but I can't get normal SMS just those that go from client to server

Comment: You can look up examples on the Internet to extract SMS message from an app directed SMS. Then just take that message and send it to server.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Wireless Messaging API (JSR 120) you can receive SMS to a JavaME application.  However, you must register to receive SMS on a particular port, and you **cannot** read SMS from the phone's standard inbox.

Register:

```
import javax.wireless.messaging.MessageConnection;
MessageConnection connection = 
    (MessageConnection) javax.microedition.io.Connector.open("sms://:1234");
```

There are 2 different methods of receiving SMS:

- event-driven using `javax.wireless.messaging.MessageListener`
- using blocking method `javax.wireless.messaging.MessageConnection.receive()`

Comment: what do you mean "register"?? and How can a normal phone send the SMS so that the JavaME app gets it then? other than the client/server approach I have

Comment: Hi Luis, you can't send SMS to a specific port using most standard phone interfaces (or any that I've seen).  You *can* send ported SMS from one JavaME app to another, or from your "server" to a JavaME app.  

I've updated my answer to explain how to register for incoming messages.